# Watchkit add UIswitch to Glance viewcontroller

Tags: watchkit, watchos-2, apple-watch-glances

Is it possible to add a UIswitch to a glance viewcontroller?

It is not working for me though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [WatchKit Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/documentation/General/Conceptual/WatchKitProgrammingGuide/ImplementingaGlance.html):

> **Do not include interactive controls in your glance interface.** Interactive controls such as buttons, switches, sliders, and menus are not supported by glances.

Your app’s glance cannot be interactive—tapping it just launches the app.

Comment: What I do find strange is that, the music player on the Apple Watch also has a glance interface with buttons.

Comment: @Techchunky Do not confuse Apple with ordinary mortals.

Comment: Yup, system apps have their own set of rules. The Settings glance has lots of buttons in it too.